# Stuffing an array into an object that is inside an array that matches an id

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a server response that comes back as such:

```
Array[2]
  0:Object
    user: "Howard",
    id:0
  1:Object
    user: "Robin",
    id:1,
    myArray: ["mary","john","gary"] // I want to add in here.
]
```

I then have an array that I created myself. I want to add this array to where an id that === 1 like my example above. I can only imagine I have to use the key of the object that matches id === 1

```
myArray=["mary","john","gary"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `find` to find the object you want, then add the array to it like this:

```js
function addToObject(arr, id, myArr) {
  var obj = arr.find(function(o) { // sear inside arr for the object with the id === 1
    return o.id === id;
  });
  if(obj)                          // if we found an object
    obj.myArray = myArr;           // add the array myArr as a property to it
}

var arr = [{user: "Howard",id:0}, {user: "Robin",id:1}];

addToObject(arr, 1, ["some", "text"]); // add the array to the object with the id 1

console.log(arr);
```

**Note:** I assumed the IDs are unique! So for an ID `id` there will be ay most one object with that ID.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully I'm not misunderstanding the question.
just loop through the main array looking for id === 1, then access the myArray property and do what you need.

```
mainArray.forEach(function(object) {
    if(object.id === 1) {
        object.myArray = ["mary","john","gary"];
    }
}
```